# Unable to delete individual list items from unordered list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I tried to create a function to delete individual list items by using addEventListener to the unordered list which calls a function that checks if the 'delete' button was clicked for that list item. If the 'delete' button was clicked, the function is supposed to delete the list item. But it doesn't seem to be working. Below is the code:

```html
<!doctype html>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='listStyle.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 id='heading'>grocery list</h2>
        <p>enter item into text box and press "enter" or click "submit".</p>
        <p>to remove item, click "remove".</p>
        <p>to reset list, click "reset".</p>
            <input type = 'text' id = 'item' name = 'item'><br><br>
            <button id = 'myBtn' onclick = 'myFunction()'>submit</button>
            <button onclick = 'resetFcn()'>reset</button>
        </form>
        <script>
        
            var str = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
            var strUpper = str[0].innerHTML.toUpperCase();
            document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = strUpper;
            
            var res = document.createElement('ul');
            res.setAttribute('id', 'myUL');
            res.addEventListener('click', delBtn);
            
            var input = document.getElementById('item');
            input.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
                if(event.keyCode===13) {
                    document.getElementById('myBtn').click();
                }
            });
                        
            function myFunction() {
                let x = document.getElementById('item').value;
                if (x == '') {
                    alert ('enter input before submitting');
                }
                else {
                    document.body.appendChild(res);
                    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
                    const node = document.createTextNode(x);
                    
                    var btn = document.createElement('button');
                    btn.innerHTML = 'remove';
                    btn.setAttribute('id', x);
                    btn.setAttribute('class', 'delete');
                    
                    var att= document.createAttribute('style');
                    att.value = 'float: right';
                    btn.setAttributeNode(att);
                    
                    listItem.append(x, ' ');
                    listItem.appendChild(btn);                   
                    res.appendChild(listItem);
                    item.value = '';
                }
            }
            
            function resetFcn() {
                while (res.firstChild) {
                    res.removeChild(res.firstChild);
                }
            }
            
            function delBtn() {
                if(event.target.classList.contains('delete')){
                    event.target.closest('listItem').remove();
                }
            }       
            
        </script>

    </body>
    
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the click handler of the delete button inside your `myFunction` function:

```
function myFunction() {
    let x = item.value;
    if (x == '') {
        alert ('enter input before submitting');
    }
    else {
        const listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.innerText = x;

        const btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.innerText = 'remove';

        btn.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
            listItem.remove();
        }); //this way you can delete the list item because it is in the same scope

        listItem.appendChild(btn);
        myUl.appendChild(listItem);
        item.value = '';
    }
}
```

This is outside your question but I would also clean up your code, remove the closing form tag, use `const`/`let` in stead of `var`. Do not use `keyCode` because it is deprecated, ...

I also inserted the `ul` element in your html:

```
<ul id="myUl">

</ul>

const myUl = document.getElementById("myUl");
```

For your reset function you can just set the innerHtml of the `ul` to an empty string in stead of looping through all the elements:

```
function resetFcn() {
    myUl.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Hope this helped, good luck!